# Order multiple column variables pandas cross tab

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a data frame and I have used pd.crosstab to tabulate the data.
I am using multiple column variables but am struggling to reorder them.
Using:

```
pd.crosstab(df['id'], [df['treatment'],df['timepoint']])
```

Outputs:

```
treatment   A           B           C
timepoint   post    pre post    pre post    pre
id                      
1           0       0   0       0   76      32
10          0       0   1       4   0       0
11          0       0   0       0   0       5
12          1       4   0       0   0       0
13          0       0   0       0   4       0
```

I want to be able to reorder the treatments in the order of C, A, B and the timepoint in the order of pre, post.

Is this possible. I know that I can take a slice of the data in the order I want if only using and index and single column variable, but not with multiple column variables.

I know you can use colnames= to change the name of the columns, but I can't seem to be able to reorder them.

Any help will be appreciated.